# Set content to edge of Cardview pre 5.0

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm using the `CardView` layout from the v7 support library as a primary design pattern in my app. It works great on Lollipop as you'd expect and looks like this:

[image]

If I run this same app on 4.4 or below the content in the card doesn't go to the edge as seen here:

[image]

Is there a way that I can get the content to go to the edges on all versions of Android and not just 5.0?

Thanks

Comment: please, attach your card layout xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the creators of the CardView didn't come up with an efficient way to create rounded corners that would work for any layout on devices running earlier versions that Lollipop. Because of that, padding is simply added to the content of the cards. To prevent this padding use this method:

```
cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
```

If you do this however, the ImageView's corners will be drawn over the rounded corners of the CardView. A solution to this problem is to create a custom ImageView (or Drawable, or Picasso transfromation...) that draws rounded corners. Check this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/f5a176f1b941200fac68) on how to do that.

Since you are using a common layout for cards with a header image, you could check [this library](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) by the same author which creates the rounded corners without padding.